# Iterating through arrays of objects in meteor templates

Tags: meteor, spacebars

```
[
  {name:"foo",last:"bar",age:100},
  {name:"baz",last:"foobar",age:200},
]
```

Is there a way on how to iterate that to a meteor template using {{#each}} helper like

```html
<template name='boo'>
  {{#each objectInArray}}
    <span> {{namehere}} </span>
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```html
<template name="boo">
  {{#each objectInArray}}
    <span> {{foo}} </span>
    <span> {{last}} </span>
    <span> {{age}} </span>
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

```js
Template.boo.objectInArray = function() {
  return [
    {name:"foo",last:"bar",age:100},
    {name:"baz",last:"foobar",age:200},
  ]
}
```

Comment: Exception from Deps recompute function: TypeError: Cannot read property 'objectInArray' of undefined

Comment: OMG, `<template name='boo'>`, so it should be `Template.` **boo** `.objectInArray`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19754196/how-do-i-modify-spark-js-im-getting-the-following-error-exception-from-deps-r[link]  got the answer from here.

Comment: Thуn I have no idea what exactly you asked!